# Does any research/study exist on what makes an interactive document better from a user experience perspective?

Tags: interaction-design, graphic-design, page-layout, interactive-ui, pdf

I am aware that there is a lot of research into page layout methodologies and the flow of design elements (text, diagrams, etc) such as the Gutenberg Diagram, Z-Pattern, F-Pattern, and so on. I'm also aware of other Stack Exchange questions (e.g. this recent one: [Page layout - authoritative research into natural flow of text, tables and images](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/92822/page-layout-authoritative-research-into-natural-flow-of-text-tables-and-image)).

However, this question is about interactive documents (typically interactive PDFs, but not necessarily so).

I have designed many of these over the years and after coming across the question above, got to thinking that maybe there is some respected research into what makes an interactive document much more usable from a reader's point of view.

Typically (though not always) my interactive PDFs are designed so that they're almost like an entire website within a PDF (i.e. they have a menu structure and make use of images, colour, white space etc). Users can browse and jump around seamlessly within the document as required and these seem to work very well. I've used this approach for technical documents, newsletters, interactive diagrams, help guides and so on and these seem to come across very well, but I'm always looking to continually improve my work.

For example, one area I haven't delved too much into is the use of javascript in my interactive PDFs. I have used this on two occasions with positive results, but I'm not sure if there are any dos and don'ts on using javascript.

Also, I wonder about the compatibility of interactive PDFs with screen reader software for the visually impaired?

And of course, with the explosion of mobile platforms, there's the whole issue of compatibility to ensure that an interactive document displays and functions as intended from Mac/Windows desktops to iOS/Windows Mobile/Android devices.

Obviously, there's quite a bit to this topic, hence why my question is asking for references to any research (if it exists) on best practice for creating interactive documents. My hope is that if any research does exist, some or most of these issues will be covered.

Comment: Perhaps the biggest problem here is Apple's failure to make iBooks Author capable of deep and profound interactivity. So we don't even know what creative people might do with the ability to make interactive books/documents because it's too much of a stretch to expect them to nut out JavaScript and other means of exploring creative options. And we all know it's impossible for programmers to listen to designers and explore their ideas for them in an assistive manner.

Comment: Yes, I do feel your frustration. A couple of my interactive PDFs required 3rd party software to behave as intended when viewed on iPads and iPhones. Even Adobe's offering for iOS didn't display them properly. This was about 18 months ago, so I'm not sure how much has changed in that time. While I think Apple makes the right judgment call on most things, I do agree with you that this isn't one of them.

Comment: In 18 months (going on 3 years) there's no significant increase in the powers of interactive book creation software and tools. You haven't missed anything. It's still a quagmire of archaic metaphors for outdated modes of communication with little (or zero) consideration for the powers of interactive content. This problem is not new, unfortunately. Guys like Ted Nelson (that conceived of hyperlinking in the early 60's) have only seen small percentages of their inventive and idealised interpretations of possible future mediums realised because of... I don't really know why. Commercial control?

Comment: Aah yes, Ted Nelson. I remember reading that he felt Tim Berners-Lee had successfully achieved part of his vision by inventing the WWW, but that in a sense html (which drives the web) was exactly the sort of thing he wanted to prevent. This apparent contradiction piqued my curiosity and delving into Nelson's work more was a bit of a mind blast - things like broken hyperlinks never being an issue if computer networks had developed along his vision of two-way linkages. Interesting stuff. No doubt in some futuristic incarnation of what we call the web today, his vision will be more prophetic.

Comment: Near as I can tell, the 70's and 80's saw much of the vision of the 60's stalled, somewhat deliberately. I suspect the desire to monitor and restrict communication was part of this, and perhaps the powers that sponsored the research felt their ability to record and analyse communication wasn't yet ready for the potential of networks. Doug Engelbart suffered most. His interactive knowledge work ideas were miles forward of now. And Ted Nelson's take on Copy/Paste and editing is how metaphors should be done. The two together make for a generational leap in user empowerment we still haven't seen

Comment: @Confused - +1 - Can you provide your comments in answer form, with a link or two? The information might not be direct research results to the question, but you frame it in a very nice way of how the idea might be floundering outside of better usability practices (existing or not) in the document scope.

Comment: what are "better usability practices in the document scope?"

Comment: @Confused - (shrug) I don't know. It's whatever improves the UX for interactive documents, per the question space. I'm making the point that while your comments might not hit directly on those aspects, you frame the information in a good way that illustrates why current practices might not be driving interactive documents in a more usability focused direction. I'm making sure suggestion you put them in an answer.

Comment: As someone who nearly exclusively uses non-Adobe, third-party PDF readers, use a website, never an "interactive" PDF. It's much easier for users to work without proprietary extensions. In terms of a usability perspective, I give up immediately when a document requires "locally installed software X". Made properly, and with a modern browser, websites are also much more compatible with screen readers, support an extremely wide variety of features, and shouldn't require special features.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the question: That the PDF format is the right solution for interactive documents. As @Kupiakos points out, a proper website has far more interaction potential. The UX benefit of e-books isn't about interaction so much as it is about convenience for users who don't like or don't have room for a physical library.

Comment: @Kupiakos To my mind, an interactive document is **not** the same as a website. They can be very similar and share some of the same attributes, but a _single_ document that is entirely portable and viewable on any computer regardless of whether it is online or not will meet the needs of many situations that a website cannot do in the same way or with the same ease. However, this has raised an interesting question, so I have asked another [question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93106/interactive-documents-v-websites-what-research-studies-exist-to-cover-when-one) to cover this as well.

Comment: @plainclothes the premise of the question has nothing to do with PDFs, other than to use them as an EXAMPLE of a document type: "this question is about interactive documents (typically interactive PDFs)". If you can think of a better format you prefer (.chm or ebook for example) this question is not excluding your choice/preference. It does exclude websites because it isn't asking about websites, its asking about documents. These might be books for sale, offline manuals, educational materials, etc etc. Think of portable documents. That's the question.

Comment: The web might have gained more interactivity over the years, but it is not a document format in the sense the question is asking. And there's legitimate markets for documents over online, gated, or otherwise secured materials. The increases in "interactivity" available in websites is a mirage created by focusing too heavily on ideas of PDF. A document could be coded in Objective-C, and utilise every feature of an iPad. It doesn't have to be thought of as a PDF or any other constrained format. It just needs to be a document in the metaphorical, yet tangible, shareable sense.

Comment: Like a webpage...

Comment: wait, you guys have never seen a webpage that works offline??? like, my_document.html that can be viewed on any platform in any standards-compliant browser without installing unknown edgy software?

Comment: @Aprillion Of course we have. But there's no way for a single .html document to be interactive without a whole heap of other interdependent files. And there are many scenarios that require a different solution to a 'website'. Refer to my related [question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93106/interactive-documents-v-websites-what-research-studies-exist-to-cover-when-one) for details.

Comment: I posted an answer to that question that pdf vs website is an implementation detail unrelated to UX - both can be non-portable with dead links, both can be offline single file documents

Comment: @Aprillion Okay, but regardless of format (.pdf, .mht, .html, .webarchive, etc) the question still stands. What makes an interactive document better from a user experience perspective?

Comment: ah, now you mention it - better than what? than static document that is like paper? doesn't that beg the question? is interactive better than static? or can paper be interactive? I have read books with branching plots that continue on different pages...

Comment: @Aprillion Maybe I should clarify my question. Assuming you're going to create an interactive document, what factors do you consider in designing it? For example, research or experience may show that including a clickable menu to all sections of the document with a 'Back to Menu' type option at the end of each section, improves the user experience. On the other hand, empirical evidence may indicate that embedding sounds is not something users find useful, but rather find irritating. So, what elements should and should not be included in an interactive document in order to maximise the UX?

Comment: yes, that should be part of the question :) + assuming the user needs are better served with interactive document, e.g. for an extensive documentation (such as in avionics maintenance or manufacturing robots) or a reference guide which users don't read from start to end, but need to find all the sections related to their particular task => for this use case, a custom search index with domain specific synonyms would be really handy

Comment: after re-reading about Ted Nelson's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Xanadu, they focused more on interconnection between documents (=> online) and not an offline interactive document, so I removed my answer and keeping only as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would narrow down the problem definition - documents are supposed to convey information. And to quote from Bret Victor (http://worrydream.com/MagicInk/#p155):

> Information software [...] mimics the experience of reading, not working. It is used for achieving an understanding—constructing a model within the mind. [...] **For information software, all interaction is essentially navigation around a data space.**

So this is a problem how to *design navigation*, not interactivity in general:

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation
- http://www.userzoom.com/information-architecture-optimization/how-to-nail-down-a-winning-site-navigation-by-combining-research-methods/

Other kinds of "interactive documents" are usually called *applications, tools, utilities* or *games*, so I wouldn't expect to find much useful info on the topic of "user experience of interactive documents", but a lot of research on the topics of:

- application design (https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-application-design-mistakes/)
- graphic design (http://worrydream.com/#!/MagicInk)
- document design (https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/wc128)
- interaction design (http://worrydream.com/#!/ABriefRantOnTheFutureOfInteractionDesign or [The Art of Interactive Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1886411840))
- how it happened that we create badly designed software (e.g. [The Inmates Are Running the Asylum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1886411840))

Answer (score 7):

There is very little current research, possibly because the use cases for interactive documents has been taken over by the web, and in parallel, the increase in availability of devices and connectivity.

One paper that discusses the attributes of an interactive document can be found at PubMed Central from 2011, ['Interactive Publication: The document as a research tool'](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908409/).

Key passage:

> We consider the following attributes necessary for an interactive publication.
>
> - Appearance:
>     Paginated view of the document should be similar to that of a   traditional article, implying the availability of a large variety of
>     fonts, weights, styles, paragraphing, multi-column formatting, etc.
> - Page transitions: Traditional use of keyboard keys (page up/down) and
>     mouse (scroll bar) should be possible.
> - In-page navigation: Traditional use of keyboard keys (cursor
>     up/down/left/right) and mouse, as well as additional use of control
>     keys (as shortcuts).
> - Image browsing: Commonly used image formats, such as JPEG, PNG, TIFF,
>     DICOM, should be natively supported. It should be easy to encode some degree of interaction with these into the document model.
> - Navigating to an embedded / linked media object: Mouse-click (or
>     keyboard) activation of audio, video and other objects should be
>     possible.
> - Embedded or linked media: objects should be able to invoke appropriate
>     viewers or players.
> - Native support for interactivity: The document model should provide
>     native support for adding interactivity to tabular data, images and
>     other multimedia data.
>
>   - The document model should allow authors to
>       define metadata needed to control interactivity with multimedia data,
>       e.g., start-frame and end-frame numbers for video, row-column
>       selections in a table, etc.
>   - These metadata could enhance the reader’s
>       interaction with the document. Data in specialized and proprietary
>       formats should be viewable using appropriate supporting application
>       software.
> - Transmission: The document model should support a reader-controlled
>     order of transmission for data intensive multimedia-rich documents
>     for convenient usage.
> - Embedding and linking of multimedia/interactive objects: The document 
>     model should support both embedding and linking of multimedia and
>     other interactive data such as dynamic tables or active images.
> - Document integrity and structure: It is imperative that the document
>     be self-contained.
>
>   - **That is, the multimedia components should exist
>       within the document, and not simply exist in remote databases at,
>       say, publishers’ Web sites. This is important for several reasons,
>       including the need for major libraries to preserve the scientific
>       record, a difficult task if the contents of the document were
>       scattered in remote locations.**
>   - The document model should support
>       document integrity by closely linking the text document to the
>       multimedia components. However, for a reader who might not be
>       interested in downloading the datasets associated with the
>       publication, a streaming media service should be available as an
>       alternative.

The bolded text is where I believe the key advantage of an interactive document lies over an interactive website (for example). [Link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) is a problem that will only increase on the web, and as a key UX differentiator - the ability to be confident all the content you built into the document when published will still be there in `x years` time is a benefit to using an interactive document.

This clearly will not answer all your secondary questions - but those are quite specific, and may realistically require you to do some gather some first-party data, or infer from existing research on non-interactive documents.

Comment: "likely because a significant amount of the use cases for interactive documents has been taken over by the web" this needs some supporting evidence, of some sort.

Comment: I've changed the qualifier on that statement.

Answer (score 3):

Don Norman attempted to do a multimedia version for three of his books a while ago. From what I know, the experiment wasn't a success, you can probably find more about it online. He also talks about it in the last version of Design of Everyday Things.

It is called First Person and here is a short video showcasing some of the ineractions
[First Person : Don Norman](https://vimeo.com/18687931)

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_Books) is a wiki entry about the company and their expanded books initiatives.

Answer (score 1):

The initial premise or assumption of your question that having some research that you can reference address these issues

> My hope is that if any research does exist, some or most of these
>   issues will be covered.

is probably going to set up unreasonable expectations. As you know, research is designed to answer specific questions under a specific set of circumstances, so the extent to which you can extrapolate those findings to your situation is going to be limited by the scope of the research. Based on the bounty amount you have put up and the number of responses/references provided I would suggest that it is unlikely to address all the issues you have raised.

Let me try to provide a logical way to look at the things you should consider, and let you come to your own conclusions:

- **Self-containment**: this appears to be an advantage to your users in terms of providing a 'better' user experience on interactive documents compared to web pages. In essence is true in many ways, not just because you can download a copy and run it in your own environment (if you have the right software - but most people will have a compatible browser for web pages so keep that in mind). But if the interactive document depends on other software applications then it loses that advantage.
- **Performance**: this is probably also an advantage of interactive documents, but it depends on how they are implemented. I have seen lots of PDF documents with 3d models embedded and usually I don't open it in a browser tab but the equivalent application. But this is probably more due to network speed than anything else.
- **Accessibility**: I am guessing that it might be easier to make a webpage accessible but I believe that the medium you use, regardless of where it is embedded will introduce similar problems. PDF files can also be designed to be accessible so it also comes down to implementation methods.
- **Richness of interaction**: I guess this is largely a technology issue, and by default one might imagine that designing a webpage gives you more flexibility and access to a richer range of interactive and multimedia content. Whether this has impact on other aspects of the user experience depends on how it is implemented, but in general you might expect the solution you use for creating the interactive document would pose more constraints on what you can and cannot design into the user interaction.
- **Maintenance/freshness**: I believe that it would be easier to maintain and update online documents because people often overlook documents when making updates and changes to the content as it is not generally dynamically linked to the rest of the website. Having said that, it still comes down to implementation details and any particular constraints you might have.
- **Overall user experience**: I guess if you look at each of these factors individually for your situation, and work out the pros and cons in the way you implement webpages or interactive documents, you'll find that if done correctly there's probably not that much difference to the user. Any research you look at is going to give webpages or interactive documents a higher rating than the other for each of these aspects. Understanding how it applies in your situation is going to help you justify your decision to implement content in one way as opposed to an alternative solution.